# Why does .local only work in online mode firefox

Tags: firefox, offline, www

When I open john.local page in firefox, when Wifi is on, it works perfectly.

But when I turn off Wifi the page doesn't work anymore, plus firefox adds www before john.local, like this:

> www.john.local

Even if I type john.local, firefox redirects me to www.john.local, and I get server not found.

When I switch the developer's mode to work offline(firefox settings), I am directed to john.local(in the URL part there is no www), and the page opens.(I don't get server not found anymore).

How can I get rid of www? Because www seems to be the problem.

I want to work with john.local, while Wifi is off, and developer mode in firefox is "work online".

I have already added the entry john.local in /etc/hosts.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it's a bit unclear. can you edit the question and change your sentence structure?

Comment: @MarkYisri I edited it, but me english is not that good. I can provide screenshots as well, if it is still unclear.